# BMR Calculator program

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an application to calculate BMR. This is what  I wrote below so far:  You just enter your height in CM and enter weight in Kilograms.But, when I will calculate the BMR,  the button isn't working.

**Gender**
                    
                    Male
                    Female
                    
                
               
             
            
            
            
                 
                  **Age**

```
                     <tr>
                     <td class="height">Your Height<strong></strong>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                     <input type="number" name="height" id="height" tabindex="7" value="height" min="50"  >Centimeter
                     </td>
                     </tr>
                 
               
                
                  <tr>
                     <td class="weight">Your Weight<strong></strong></td>
                     <td>
                     <input type="number" id="weight" name="Weight" tabindex="13" value="weight" min="100" >Kilograms
                     </td>
                  </tr>
        
                      
                    <p>
                        Select your activity level:
                    </p>
                    
                        
                    
                      <td class="activity">
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="15" value="1.53"> Rarely or no exercise </td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="17" value="1.76"> Ligthly or 1 - 3 days per week  </td> </tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="19" value="1.76"> Moderate or 3-5 days per week </td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="21" value="2.25"> Active or 6-7 days per week  </td> </tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="23"  value="2.25"> Super active or very hard exercise</td></tr>
                      </td>

                     <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Calculate_bmr" onclick="Calculate_bmr()";>
                        <button type="reset" onclick="clearErr()">Reset</button>
                     </td>
                    </table>


                    
                    
                
</form>

<script src="Assignment1.js"></script>
```

Here's my function

function Calculate_bmr(){

```
   var bmr;
var age = document.getElementsByName("age").Value;
var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender").value;
var height = document.getElementsByName("height").value;
var weight = document.getElementsByName("weight").value;
var activity = document.getElementsByName("activity").value;
```

}

I know it is horrible. I have been trying all day not sure where is mistake.

switch(activity) {

```
case "1.53":

if(gender = "male"){

    bmr = (66.5 + (13.75 * weight) + (5.003 * height) + (6.755 * age)) * 1.53;
    window.alert(bmr);
    break;

} else {

    bmr = (655 + (9.563*weight) + (1.850*height) + (4.676*age)) * 1.53;
    break;

}
case "1.76":
    if(gender = "male"){

        bmr = (66.5 + (13.75*weight) + (5.003*height) + (6.755*age)) * 1.76;
        window.alert(bmr);
        break;
    
    } else {
    
        bmr = (655 + (9.563*weight) + (1.850*height) + (4.676*age)) * 1.76;
        break;
    
    }
case "2.25":
    if(gender = "male"){

        bmr = (66.5 + (13.75*weight) + (5.003*height) + (6.755*age)) * 2.25;
        window.alert(bmr);
        break;
    
    } else {
    
        bmr = (655 + (9.563*weight) + (1.850*height) + (4.676*age)) * 2.25;
        break;
    
    }

}
```

Comment: First, don't use table-element for formatting. Second, your variables selectors don't have any class on input-element, It should be `document.getElementsByName('Name')`. Read more about here about selectors [https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_selectors.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_selectors.asp). Third, the switch case is looking for Gender but the values are '1.53, 1.76, 2.25'.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it . It's the Calculate_bmr button is not working. Reset button is unlike the other

Answer (score 0):

So in order for you to get the value of the activity, you need to loop on each and check if it's 'checked' or not and get its value.

```js
function Calculate_bmr(){

var bmr;
var elements_activity = document.getElementsByName('activity');
var activity;
elements_activity.forEach(e => {
  if (e.checked) {
    //if radio button is checked, set the value
    //you can get the value of activity by checking each loop of the elements activity
    activity = e.value;
  }
});
alert(activity);
}
```

```html
<p>
                        Select your activity level:
                    </p>
                    
                        
                    
                      <td class="activity">
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="15" value="1.53"> Rarely or no exercise </td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="17" value="1.76"> Ligthly or 1 - 3 days per week  </td> </tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="19" value="1.76"> Moderate or 3-5 days per week </td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="21" value="2.25"> Active or 6-7 days per week  </td> </tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity" tabindex="23"  value="2.25"> Super active or very hard exercise</td></tr>
                      </td>

                     <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Calculate_bmr" onclick="Calculate_bmr()";>
                        <button type="reset" onclick="clearErr()">Reset</button>
                     </td>
                    </table>
```

After you get the value of the activity. Remember that the height, weight, and activity are all string and you need to convert it to a number in order to do any operation such as

```
bmr = (66.5 + (13.75 * weight) + (5.003 * height) + (6.755 * age)) * 1.53;
```

But the Switch case you have is asking for a string '1.53, 1.76, 2.25', so you need to convert the activity after the switch case:

So Converting a String to a Number: You can use ParseInt or Number, just learn more about here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp